I want to see my whole file in pycharm while I am working so I have a better Idea of what I'm doing is it even doable?
So I have a file a couple hundred lines and I want to see the full file on the side or something I know its theoretically achievable however I don't know if its in pycharm I know its theoretically possible because I have seen it in teams when I shared an earlier version of the file.
I haven't seen anything in settings I guess I can send it to myself and look at it in a different window but it doesn't update.

Sounds like you are looking for plugin like Code Glance Pro https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/18824-codeglance-pro

exactly what I'm looking for thanks !
